# Shell performance in .NET MAUI (Android)

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, maui

I decided to develop an app using .NET MAUI (xaml), that is now in RC. I use shell page as a base, and found out that there's a significant lag/glitch in a following scenario:

1. Open flyout menu
2. Click on some navigation button
3. Flyout menu starts closing. At this moment there's a glitch, like it tries to render a page you navigate to and close the menu in the same thread. The more complex page you have, the longer the glitch takes place. But even if you have a blank page, it still happens. I think it's either me doing it wrong or there are issues with .NET MAUI shell.

Looking through the Internet I found an issue in github about similar problem in Xamarin: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7521 . I suppose it happens in MAUI because the issue migrated from Xamarin, but it's ridiculous that it hasn't been fixed for 2 years. There are some workarounds there, but all of them are not good for me to use.

Does anyone know how to resolve this app freeze in MAUI/Xamarin?
Also, is it possible to have a fully functional flyout menu in MAUI Blazor (a menu that can respond to swipe gestures)?

P.s. I don't attach the code as it's pretty basic, you can just add 2 blank pages to navigate to, and you'll notice the time delay when the menu closes. I test it on Samsung Galaxy A8.

Comment: While it may be "basic" you're still expecting someone to build this basic app when you could provide it. Doing so might help you get some attention.

Comment: I would also be interested in a solution to this. The problem has always been present in Xamarin, and now also in MAUI. I think Microsoft is largely pretending that the problem doesnt exist because they dont know how to fix it.